# KNOW THUSELF: What OOP languages really support true self-reference keyword not just "this" keyword?

Tags: oop, self-reference

As I read here Lua has a self

[How does an object reference itself in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066886/how-does-an-object-reference-itself-in-lua)

But is it really self in the sense that WHATEVER THE CONTEXT self always refers to the object itself. Seems like a tautology but no consider the this keyword, it isn't self object it is rather the object WHERE the  code is being executed.

Update: I'm not refering to javascript only but to all languages : this exists in js, .net java ... and is not semantically self (so these languages are not candidates) which should be INVARIANT (like in mathematical sense) whereas "this" is not invariant: it can change during the same execution flow.

My question is precisely support of real "self" keyword with INVARIANCE feature - don't answer workaround like closure :).

"KNOW THUSELF" is important not only for people but for Object. How can you do perfect encapsulation when object cannot self  reference itself for sure ?

Comment: Do you mean the `this` keyword in Javascript?

Comment: Your question is a bit cryptic. What would you consider a "true self-reference keyword"?

Comment: "... self always refers to the object itself."  **What** object are we talking about here?  Code is code; what sort of relationship between some code units (of what type?) and "objects" is at issue here?

Comment: How is this java, javascript, **and** .net?

Comment: I'm not refering to javascript only but to all languages : this exists in js, .net java ... and is not semantically self. which should be INVARIANT whereas "this" is not invariant: it can change during the same execution flow.

Comment: than it's better to remove all language specific tags which I just did.

Comment: @user310291: Not true. Only in javascript does the value of the `this` keyword change.

Comment: ok I'll try to find examples for .net have forgotten them so will take some time.

Comment: Certainly in Java, the this pointer never changes.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the `this` keyword refers to whichever object the function belongs to. However, the problem is that the the functions change ownership. If for example you have this:

```
function Foo(a) {
    this.bar = a;
    this.baz = function() {
        alert(this.bar)
    }
}

var foo = new Foo("foobar");
foo.baz();
// Alerts "foobar"

var baz = foo.baz;
// Copy the method into the window object, changing its ownership

baz();
// Alerts "undefined"

var fixedBaz = baz.bind(foo);
fixedBaz();
// Alerts "foobar"
```

The member function changes its ownership at `var baz = foo.baz;`, so the `this` keyword points to the `window` object instead.

I think a better question is "How do I reference a member function of an object while maintaining the original `this` pointer".

#### EDIT:

You can use the [`function.bind`](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-1-ecmascript-bound-functions/) method to lock the `this` pointer to a certain value.

Comment: If I ask your question I'm pretty sure people are going to answer closure ;) Precisely I want simple "self" keyword not closure.

Comment: thanks for the example will look at it I have difficulty to imagine one because I got some in the past and I forgot.

Comment: function.bind never heard seems what I'm looking for thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to understand what you are talking about ... and I'm starting to think that is because what you are saying is nonsensical.

> this exists in js, .net java ... and is not semantically self. which should be INVARIANT whereas "this" is not invariant: it can change during the same execution flow.

Yes. It is a fact that `this` will refer to different objects at different times, and that (for example) when you call a method on some other object `this` will refer to that other object ... while executing that method.

This is well understood, and obviously useful ... so there's no need to go into it further.

So what would it mean if `this` didn't change when you called a method on a different object?  Presumably it would refer to the original object.

- But **which** original object would it refer to?  The value of `this` in the caller?  But where did **that** come from?
- And how would such a semantic model of `this` be useful?  I'm struggling to think of any use cases for such a `this` that couldn't be implement better using `static` variables.

The other possibility is that you are talking entirely from the perspective of Javascript, where `this` is indeed rather complicated ... and assuming that `this` is equally complicated in typical OO languages.  Well `this` is not complicated in the context of Java, C# or C++.

Comment: I'm not saying that this is useless, I'm asking for another keyword which is not same as this. By the way you're playing the devil's advocate 66.6 K :)

Comment: otherwise why would js have created function.bind method to lock the this pointer to a certain value.

Comment: @user310291 - basically because Javascript has a peculiarly complicated model of `this` ... which is not shared with most other OO languages.

Comment: ok I'll come back to this thread in a few days when I'll have finished with learning Flash :)