# Gideros how to pass a function to Timer.delayCall?

Tags: timer, lua, gideros

First, it is possible to do like this:

```
local delay = 1000
local timer = Timer.delayedCall(delay, 
                                function(data) 
                                    print(data)
                                end, 
                                20)
```

But, it seems not possible to do like this:

```
function Game:DoSomething(data)
   print(data)
end

local timer = Timer.delayedCall(delay, 
                                self.DoSomething, 
                                20)
```

In other words, I would like to define the function outside (so to be reused by others). However, that seems not possible. Or did I do it wrong?

Comment: Do not define as `Game:DoSomething`. Just `DoSomething`. Also, no need for `self.DoSomething`. `self` is not available outside of method body.

Comment: oO. Now I feel stupid. I thought Reason define as `Game:DoSomething` is that it is inside a `Sprite` Class. But it is not necessary to do it that way... Thanks for this.  Can I ask a little bit more? now it works if I just `DoSomething`, but how to access 'self's property in the `DoSomething`?

Comment: There is no `self` if not a method definition. Please read: https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066886/1190388

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is have Timer.delayedCall call a method with multiple arguments in a generic way, you can do it like this:

```
function Game:DoSomething(data)
   print(data)
end

function invokeMethod(args)
    local func=table.remove(args,1)
    func(unpack(args))
end

local timer = Timer.delayedCall(
      delay,
      invokeMethod,
      {self.DoSomething,self,20}) --self is the instance you are calling
```

PS: this is my first post on SO, sorry if it isn't formatted correctly...